# Error after upgrade to 11.04 from 10.10 - Does not mount volumes correctly

Tags: 11.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu version from 10.10 to 11.04 alpha and on reboot got an error "The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present  Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.

When I press M I get the normal command prompt, how do I get the correct drive mounted??

Comment: Please see this thread and file a bug: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate

Comment: same problem jacked fstab and mtab with old style device layout no success date 2.22.2011 if fix was in I didnt get it with online update!

Comment: Just had the same problem on my laptop. Did an upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 yesterday. All went smoothly, rebooted a few times all ok.
Decided to install more updates today, reboot and now getting the same error message.
I booted via PartedMagic and my fstab is using UUID.
Am able to mount the drive without any problems in PartedMagic.
It contains # out entries for the old format of /dev/sda1 etc.
Changing to /dev/sd made no difference.

Comment: Well I've now used the Live CD to perform an upgrade, all went through OK. Reboot, same error!

Answer (score 3):

First guess is that there is an incorrect entry in /etc/fstab.
Another possibility (hope not) is that something is wrong with one or more partitions or the drive / controller.

Suggestions:
-boot from liveCD/liveUSB and check integrity of partitions (using gparted for example)
-mount your root partition and take a look at /etc/fstab for anything wrong (you might try using /dev/sd? instead of UUID?)
-worst case scenario, there is a repair install option from the liveCD/liveUSB

Answer (score 2):

You should restart the update manager again. There was an update that was justed released for that not to long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Root filesystem check fails after power failure during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation/40058#40058)

It worked for me.