# Messed up partitions after 11.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, partitioning, mount

I wanted to upgrade my old 10.10 to 12.04 using alternate CD, and had to upgrade to 11.04 first. Unfortunately I ran into the following error after upgrading and rebooting to ubuntu :

> the disk drive for /boot is not yet ready or not present

.. with options to either ignore the error or manually repair.

Ignoring the error led to the same message with "/home" and them prompted the ubuntu log-in screen. Once logged, several errors messages popped up and no GUI was displayed, leaving no other option than to reboot.

Solutions for similar problems were given here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1724209 and there: [Root filesystem check fails after power failure during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during) installation (remount the root partition, then launch an update) but in my case that didn't fixed the issue.

My pc is configured as a dualboot windows7/ubuntu 64 bits on a Raid0, using two HD. My /etc/fstab is as following :

```
/dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume06 /     ext4 errors = remount-ro
/dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume03 /boot ext4 defaults
/dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume07 /home ext4 defaults
/dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume05 none  swap defaults
```

Using fsck -a and mount -a lead me to the following messages :

fsck -a :

```
fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume06
```

mount -a :

```
mount: special device /dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume03 does not exist
mount: special device /dev/mapper/isw_djibifgbhd_Volume07 does not exist
```

When booting on a live CD, gparted could not recognized my partitions (just the two hard disks) while disk utility still detect how the different drives were configured.

I assume I just have to make the system recognize the volumes somehow. The solution may be trivial, but I am not used to deal with this kind of problems and I don't know how to resolve this issue.

If someone can give me some hints about how to proceed, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Solved there : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12493772#post12493772

(names of the fakeraid partitions got edited somehow during the upgrade)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.