# Why is the upgrade manager freezing when upgrading to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

Earlier today I started to upgrade to 13.10 only to return much much later and notice that the update manager was still running.

[image]

It seems to be frozen and I am reluctant to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I can't launch nautilus using the icon on the launcher. When I try to run it via the terminal, this is what happens:

```
$ nautilus
Could not register the application: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: 
No such interface `org.gtk.Actions' on object at path /org/gnome/Nautilus
```

My printers aren't showing up when I attempt to print. I don't know whether these a symptoms of the same problem. Should I let the update manage continue to run, or should I shut it down?

Here are the processes running if it is any help:

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2   5920  4072 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:02 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:31 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [kworker/u:0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kworker/u:0H]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [migration/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:54 [rcu_sched]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:43 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [migration/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [cpuset]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [khelper]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [netns]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kblockd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [khubd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [md]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:09 [kswapd0]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct18   0:00 [ksmd]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct18   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthre
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [crypto]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [binder]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [deferwq]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [charger_manage
root       166  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       167  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       188  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       244  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [kworker/u:4]
root       245  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       260  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       267  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   1:08 [usb-storage]
root       268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       269  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:06 [usb-storage]
root       302  0.0  0.0   2904   504 ?        S    14:11   0:00 upstart-udev-br
root       305  0.0  0.0  12080  1632 ?        Ss   14:11   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       329  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:24 [jbd2/sda2-8]
root       330  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwri
root       352  0.0  0.0   2944     4 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /sbin/ureadahea
root       440  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:05 [flush-8:0]
root       734  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [cfg80211]
root       761  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       780  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [pccardd]
root       784  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clea
root       902  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [hd-audio0]
syslog     916  0.0  0.0  31120   680 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:13 rsyslogd -c5
102       1010  0.0  0.1   4344  1988 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:04 dbus-daemon --s
root      1061  0.0  0.0   4844   924 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluet
root      1077  0.0  0.0   2268   388 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/in
root      1079  0.0  0.0   4664   484 tty4     Ss+  Oct18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 
root      1087  0.0  0.0   4664   484 tty5     Ss+  Oct18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 
root      1089  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [krfcommd]
root      1098  0.0  0.0   4664   484 tty2     Ss+  Oct18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 
root      1099  0.0  0.1   4408  2076 tty3     Ss   Oct18   0:00 /bin/login --  
root      1101  0.0  0.0   4664   484 tty6     Ss+  Oct18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 
root      1168  0.0  0.0   2780   524 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 cron
daemon    1169  0.0  0.0   2636   212 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 atd
root      1183  0.0  0.0  34872  1448 ?        SLsl Oct18   0:00 lightdm
root      1249  0.0  0.0   3536   468 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/
root      1254  4.2  2.2 125832 40040 tty7     Rsl+ Oct18  81:27 /usr/bin/X :0 -
root      1261  0.0  0.0   2268   344 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/ac
root      1265  0.0  0.1  42004  2836 ?        Ssl  Oct18   0:01 NetworkManager
root      1272  0.0  0.0   2268   376 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sb
root      1286  0.0  0.3  30616  5824 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:05 /usr/lib/policy
root      1304  0.0  0.0   2268   372 ?        D    Oct18   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/li
root      1360  0.0  0.0   5532   560 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /sbin/dhclient 
nobody    1368  0.0  0.0   5476   784 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsma
root      1514  0.0  0.1  34036  1932 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:01 /usr/lib/accoun
root      1530  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 [kauditd]
root      1536  0.0  0.1  30480  2260 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:01 /usr/sbin/conso
root      1653  0.0  0.1  28908  2104 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
root      1698  0.0  0.0  17464  1388 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 lightdm --sessi
rtkit     1750  0.0  0.0  21368   696 ?        SNl  Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
1000      1844  0.0  0.1  88116  2320 ?        SLl  Oct18   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
1000      1855  0.0  0.3  73076  5884 ?        Ssl  Oct18   0:00 gnome-session -
1000      1901  0.0  0.0   4128    24 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-ag
1000      1904  0.0  0.0   3880   192 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
1000      1905  0.0  0.1   5520  2500 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:23 //bin/dbus-daem
1000      1915  0.0  0.0  43348  1420 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
1000      1919  0.0  0.0   3412  1252 ?        S    Oct18   0:01 /bin/dbus-daemo
1000      1922  0.0  0.0  17176  1624 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
1000      1932  0.0  0.5 165916  9124 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:21 /usr/lib/gnome-
1000      1947  1.9  0.2 100716  4024 ?        S<l  Oct18  37:48 /usr/bin/pulsea
1000      1949  0.0  0.0  27568  1616 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      1953  0.0  0.0  42628  1184 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//
1000      1962  0.0  0.0  14472   916 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/pulsea
1000      1964  0.0  0.1   9548  2480 ?        S    Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      1980  0.0  0.0   3764   364 ?        S    Oct18   0:43 syndaemon -i 1.
1000      1987  0.0  0.0  24476  1668 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/
1000      1990  0.0  0.4 122968  8844 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
1000      1991  0.0  0.2  80480  5392 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
1000      1992  0.0  1.2 167532 22776 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:07 nautilus -n
1000      1998  0.0  0.4 181444  7744 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 nm-applet
1000      2002  0.0  0.1  38020  2892 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      2012  0.0  0.1  59908  2664 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:24 /usr/lib/udisks
1000      2024  0.0  0.0  26456  1540 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      2028  0.0  0.0  27684  1536 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      2036  0.0  0.0  38964  1452 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      2049  0.0  0.0   3328   588 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 /sbin/mount.ntf
1000      2053  0.0  0.0  36792  1284 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      2058  0.0  0.1  53664  2364 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      2069  0.0  0.4  82816  8112 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:07 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2084  0.0  0.1  17984  2048 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      2086  0.0  0.0   2268   392 ?        Ss   Oct18   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr
1000      2087  0.0  0.7  68100 12856 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:13 /usr/bin/gtk-wi
1000      2089  0.0  0.9  98508 17756 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:13 /usr/lib/unity/
1000      2091  0.0  0.3  65380  6692 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:01 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2117  0.0  0.2  98024  3888 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2125  0.0  0.1  86644  3408 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
1000      2126  0.0  0.3  84272  6664 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2127  0.0  0.1  94384  2752 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2128  0.0  0.1  83968  2828 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2129  0.0  0.2 150020  4684 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:01 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2130  0.0  0.2  86572  3884 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
1000      2131  0.0  0.1  69352  2524 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2144  0.0  0.1  74192  3152 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
1000      2182  0.0  0.2 101120  4420 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:02 /usr/lib/gnome-
1000      2193  0.0  0.3  77752  6448 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 telepathy-indic
1000      2200  0.0  0.1  44032  2708 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/telepa
1000      2209  0.0  0.2  77664  3860 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:02 zeitgeist-datah
1000      2216  0.0  0.2  44464  4180 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:01 /usr/bin/zeitge
root      2234  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
1000      2246  0.0  1.1  93428 21256 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:02 /usr/bin/python
1000      2284  0.0  0.6 110040 11656 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:14 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2289  0.0  0.2  85632  3728 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2296  0.0  0.1  77900  3388 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2298  0.0  0.6 120356 11992 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/bin/python
1000      2300  0.0  0.1  87560  2408 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2301  0.0  0.2  91764  4404 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2303  0.0  0.2  78224  4592 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2370  0.0  0.2  74976  4908 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2372  0.0  0.4 106760  8972 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/bin/python
1000      2394  0.0  0.1  95624  2736 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2433  0.0  0.1  46640  2124 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-l
1000      2457  0.0  0.0  34496  1648 ?        Sl   Oct18   0:00 /usr/lib/libuni
root      2513  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct18   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
1000      3361  0.0  0.0   2268   396 ?        SN   07:54   0:20 /bin/sh -c /usr
root      4919  1.8  2.1 201196 38760 ?        SNl  13:29  11:25 /usr/bin/python
root      4957  0.0  0.0   3880   400 ?        SN   13:29   0:00 dbus-launch --a
root      4958  0.0  0.0   3424  1196 ?        SNs  13:29   0:05 //bin/dbus-daem
root      5128  0.0  0.0   2268   416 ?        SN   13:50   0:00 /bin/sh -c whil
root      5141  0.0  0.0   2436   508 ?        SN   13:50   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
root      5145  0.0  1.7 245280 30872 pts/1    SNs+ 13:50   0:05 /usr/bin/python
root      5159  0.0  0.4  64200  7432 ?        SNl  13:50   0:05 /usr/bin/gnome-
root      5163  0.0  0.0  27440  1552 ?        SNl  13:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      5167  0.0  0.0  42628  1648 ?        SNl  13:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//
root      9236  0.0  0.1  19112  2680 ?        Ss   14:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
root      9243  0.0  0.0  19112  1448 ?        S    14:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
whoopsie  9409  0.0  0.2  53608  4264 ?        Ssl  14:33   0:00 whoopsie
root     20087  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:34   0:00 [xfsalloc]
root     20088  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:34   0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
root     20089  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:34   0:00 [xfslogd]
root     20092  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:34   0:00 [jfsIO]
root     20093  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:34   0:00 [jfsCommit]
root     20094  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:34   0:00 [jfsCommit]
root     20095  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:34   0:00 [jfsSync]
root     20845  0.0  0.3   7980  6048 pts/2    SNs+ 14:29   0:04 /usr/bin/dpkg -
root     23330  0.0  0.0   2896   568 ?        S    14:09   0:00 upstart-file-br
root     23332  0.0  0.0   2884   572 ?        S    14:09   0:00 upstart-socket-
root     24577  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:09   0:04 [kworker/1:2]
root     24656  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:10   0:02 [kworker/0:0]
1000     24758  2.8  4.7 243692 85516 ?        Sl   23:11   0:50 compiz
root     25774  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:39   0:00 [iprt]
1000     26128  5.5 10.3 641628 187420 ?       Sl   23:27   0:46 /usr/lib/firefo
root     26374  0.0  0.0   3964   720 ?        Ss   14:39   0:02 /usr/sbin/irqba
root     26534  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:34   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root     26564  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:35   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
1000     26664  0.0  0.1   6784  3068 tty3     S+   23:36   0:00 -bash
1000     26936 15.2  1.3  67520 23672 ?        Sl   23:39   0:21 gnome-system-mo
root     26992  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:40   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root     27049  0.0  0.0   4248   288 ?        SN   23:41   0:00 sleep 30
1000     27057  9.5  0.8  68624 16140 ?        Rl   23:41   0:00 gnome-terminal
1000     27064  0.0  0.0   2440   704 ?        S    23:41   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
1000     27065  2.6  0.1   6344  2608 pts/3    Ss   23:41   0:00 bash
1000     27113  0.0  0.0   5240  1144 pts/3    R+   23:41   0:00 ps aux
root     28267  0.0  0.0   2216   632 ?        Ss   14:39   0:00 acpid -c /etc/a
root     28333  0.0  0.0   2272   552 pts/2    SN+  14:39   0:00 /bin/sh /var/li
root     29699  0.0  0.2   8384  4608 pts/2    SN+  14:40   0:00 modprobe wl
```

---

*Update*

After hitting <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> failed to stop the update manager, I right clicked the icon corresponding to the the upgrade and selected `Quit`. Then the upgrade prompted me:

**Cancel the running upgrade?**

```
The system could be in an unusable state if you cancel the upgrade. 
You are strongly advised to resume the upgrade.
```

I selected `Cancel Upgrade` and now the upgrade is frozen (not stuck as before). I don't know the name of the process so I cannot kill it through the gnome-system-monitor.

Also, I noticed that the menu bars have disappeared from open windows.

---

*Update*

I restarted lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart` and that seemingly solved the graphical issues at the time. dpkg still would not run since another process was using it. Then the computer became extremely slow and froze (felt like I was using windows!). I decided to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>sys rec</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

When the System tried to start up, there was this following message:

```
Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored.
```

No matter what I do, <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> returns the following message:

```
exit
mountall start/starting
Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored.
```

I tried booting in recovery mode and selected to repair system using dpkg and that got stuck in the same place the upgrade was stuck.

Going back into the maintenance shell, I tried:

```
$ fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
/dev/sda2: clean, 679749/18587648 files, 51278336/74323968 blocks
```

Then I tried:

```
$ fsck -f
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structures
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 679749/18587648 files(0.3% non-contiguous), 51278336/74323968 blocks
```

Right now I am using 12.10 via a thumbdrive I had lying around. Tried to repair file system using:

```
$ sudo fsck -t ext4 /dev/sdb2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_check_if_mount: Input/output error while determining whether /dev/sdb2 
is mounted.
/dev/sdb2: clean, 679749/18587648 files, 51278336/74323968 blocks
```

I made sure the partition was unmounted before trying that of course.

---

After trying `mount -o remount, rw /` and using the recommended `dpkg --configure -a` in the maintenance shell, it seem to continue upgrading where it left off (that made it pass where it was stuck on prior attempts). However, it seems to have aborted due to too many errors. I then restarted the system and it booted fine (I was happy at that point). I opened up a terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install` and while doing its thing the whole system froze. I restarted and it wouldn't boot from the drive. The partition table seems to be corrupted now. I posted a new question concerning the corrupted partition table...

Comment: [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/361332/114660) was migrated to askubuntu recently. It sounds like the problem I am having now (little flaky on the details on how the person got to this point). The problems are identical starting from the freezing and restart. I'll give the solution a try and get back with the results.

Comment: I am going to start a new question since my problem has deviated so far from the initial symptoms. After trying `mount -o remount, rw /` and using the recommended `dpkg --configure -a` in the maintenance shell, it seem to continue upgrading where it left off (it made it passed where it was stuck on prior attempts). However, it seems to have aborted due to too many errors. I then restarted the system and it booted fine (I was happy at that point). I opened up a terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install` and while doing its thing the whole system froze. I restarted and it wouldnt boot from thedrive

Comment: I then booted from my thumbdrive and ran `sudo gparted` to make sure my files were still in order. Nope. I got this message `Invalid partition table on /dev/sda -- wrong signature 5208.` On gparted the drive shows up as 2 tb unpartitioned with a red error marker next to it. This is where I am now

Comment: I posted the [new question here](http://askubuntu.com/q/362628/114660) and hopefully I can get the partition tables fixed and return to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire up a terminal, then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> the terminal in the upgrade manager/stop the upgrade and then, in the terminal, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to resume the installation of the upgrades. Then run `sudo apt-get install`. (my upgrade to 13.10 got recently interrupted by an accidental shutdown).

Comment: Thanks, excellent timing, I was just about to start messing around with it not knowing what I was doing. Hitting <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> failed to close the update manager. Do you by chance know what the process name is?

Comment: I had this problem, and killing the process `dpkg` did the trick (use `ps -A | grep dpkg` to find the process number).

Comment: Look for process with "ubuntu-release-upgrader" in the name.