# 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade hanging at "Installed fonts-ipafont-mincho"

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

Partway through my installation, the process just hangs at the message in the title.  I'm not sure it's a good idea to halt the upgrade partway through the installation.  Any idea on how to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I had to force-reboot the machine and ended up in an emergency shell. However, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/362265) made my system bootable again.

In the emergency shell you have to:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot
```