# Cannot login after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, login, login-screen, smb

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and faced the filesystem check or mount failed issue as described here: [Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10: Filesystem check or mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361332/ubuntu-13-04-to-13-10-filesystem-check-or-mount-failed#)

The solution worked but now im unable to log in to the ui. It shows the login screen and on entering the password it just flashes something from the terminal and goes back to the login screen.

Also, starting smb/cifs active directory server fails on boot.

Edit: I checked /var/log/boot.log and found that starting apparmor profiles is failing. How do i fix that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm! Turns out Trusty hadn't installed properly before the power failure which caused the `filesystem check or mount failed`.

Booted into recovery mode and ran `clean` and `dpkg`, which downloaded and installed all the necessary packages and now all is well in the world.

Comment: Good. You also failed to mention the power failure in your question. :P

Comment: Oops...well that's why we make mistakes i guess :D