# Can't login after failed upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login

I ran an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 and while upgrading the power went off. I used this post: [Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10: Filesystem check or mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361332/ubuntu-13-04-to-13-10-filesystem-check-or-mount-failed). Now I can get to the login page, but when I enter my pw, It just brings me back to the login page. I can't login as guest either. When I hit ctrl+alt+f1 it asks for my login and pw and here it says I have an incorrect login. I only have very basic knowledge of ubuntu, so could someone help me out and walk me through a fix. Thanks!