# Ubuntu 14.04/Windows 8.1 dual-booted system gets stuck at loading initial ramdisk when I try to boot ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I'll start off by saying that I am not a very advanced Ubuntu user. This whole thing started when I was running Ubuntu and got a notification of a unfinished update, so I started the update. However, part way through my computer froze and after some waiting I choose to hard reboot it. When i tried to boot Ubuntu I got a message saying the mount failed and that I could either press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery. So I went into the maintenance shell and tried

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo  dpkg --configure -a
sudo mount -o remount,ro /
sudo sync
sudo reboot
```

(A suggestion in a question that seemed similar to my problem)

This didn't seem to fix anything, so then tried `fsck -f -c /` as per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/524617/538375.

When I tried to boot it gets stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk".
So I restarted the computer and booted in recovery mode. and got

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I then rebooted and followed the instructions for part 1 of this guide: http://www.proposedsolution.com/solutions/ubuntu-booting-to-initramfs-prompt/

This left me in the same position. So I tried boot-repair-disk on a live-USB. But when I try to run the repair I get an infinite loop of it telling me `Filesystem repair requires to unmount partitions. Please close all programs. Then close this window.` despite having no programs running. I tried running the live-USB both from the BIOS and the Windows UEFI, neither worked. So instead I ran the boot info program in boot-repair-disk. Here are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16185667/

So that's where I am at. I decided to post here due to the fear that I may mess the whole thing up even more. If anyone has any suggestion of how to fix this or can point me to a tutorial that will help, I would appreciate it.

Also this is my first post on here so I apologize if I am going about this question in an incorrect manner.