# "Filesystem check or mount failed" error. How to fix without harming Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, filesystem, recovery-mode

I was trying to update Ubuntu 12.04 to a new version and the computer crashed during the process. This is a computer with Ubuntu and Windows 7 installations.

After power button reboot and after selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, the system provides a shell interface simply saying `Filesystem check or mount failed`. It also suggests to hit CTRL+D to continue booting, but after that it says `mountall start/starting` and then the same initial error.

I do not understand the mechanics of system recovery and searched this site for some info, and got to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524574/filesystem-check-or-mount-failed) question, where there is a nice explanation of potential recovery steps:

However, since I don't understand how the system works, I am a bit worried that taking this steps might affect the Windows installation I have alongside the Ubuntu one. I do not understand the basic concept of "mount" commands, hence my question.

When I run `df -h` in the recovery shell, this shows up:

```
Filesystem Size (...) Mounted on 
udev       3.9G       /dev
tmpfs      1.6G       /run
/dev/sda6  92G        /
```

I suppose the `/dev/sda6` only corresponds to a disk partition where Ubuntu is installed.

Is there a possibility that these recovery steps might affect the windows installation/files? Apologies for the noob question, but I really lack understanding of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your best (and simplest) course of action is to [boot into recovery mode](//wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode) and select the "`fsck – check all filesystems`" option from the recovery menu (in step 7 of the linked article, instead of the "root shell" option).

Comment: Hello David thanks for your response, can you please elaborate on your answer? What does fsck does exactly and will it affect the Windows installation in another partition?