# Raid filesystem check or mount failed (after probable physical shock)

Tags: 14.04, mount, raid, fstab

As this relates to an old version of ubuntu, I have now posted the question to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/986489/raid-filesystem-check-or-mount-failed-after-probable-physical-shock).

I work on a server where the operating system is installed on an SSD but data storage is on internal harddrives set up in a RAID system. Recently I have been unable to mount the raid system when booting, while the operating system loads fine. I suspect technicians hit the server while it was running, due to scratches on the case but I am not sure.

When I boot the computer I get the error message `The drive for /home is not ready or present` (the same message for `/Data` and `/Backup`.  I entered the recovery shell and ran `fsck -A` as suggested in the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524574/filesystem-check-or-mount-failed), but I get the message that `/` was busy.

I then booted into recovery mode and ran `fsck -A`, but I get the message that

```
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=334eef34-16c4-45ec-9cc9-5f40e9f8207d'
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=19bf1002-fa4b-4462-9ea6-807d5b0f312b'
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=0f556fa7-b061-4c22-b84b-97e2e3f1b545'
```

At [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=859779) I found the suggestion to edit `/etc/fstab` but I am out of my depth here as I do not really understand what I am messing with.

running `blkid` returns

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7c05724f-61bd-4d70-b908-f6c83c4365b8" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="51978b9f-747b-4f41-8b2b-42f3da3347e6" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="13151e15-3890-90d5-d910-8ab781fc713f" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="05322b31-8961-f57d-143b-877123c61d7c" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="85430436-4dfc-96ff-083c-0734a76ff8b6" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sde1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="05feb9dd-9c4f-bc2f-50e7-c4422419268a" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdf1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="3ef48a37-14b5-1fc8-1eed-48eca24f0043" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="5960eff8-d60b-c206-90b9-c448723f9ef3" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

and running `cat /etc/fstab` prints

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7c05724f-61bd-4d70-b908-f6c83c4365b8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /Backup was on /dev/md0p2 during installation
UUID=334eef34-16c4-45ec-9cc9-5f40e9f8207d /Backup         ext4    defaults        0       2
# /Data was on /dev/md0p1 during installation
UUID=19bf1002-fa4b-4462-9ea6-807d5b0f312b /Data           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/md0p3 during installation
UUID=0f556fa7-b061-4c22-b84b-97e2e3f1b545 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=51978b9f-747b-4f41-8b2b-42f3da3347e6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I noticed that the missing UUIDs are the same as the ones in `/etc/fstab/` but does not match the ones in `blkid`. Is there some way to figure out which UUIDs goes where and restore the file system?

The vast majority is backed up so the damage is not great, but there are a few things that would be nice to restore.

I work on a server with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, if that makes a difference.

Comment: For whatever reason your workstation cannot contact the raid array on the server. Can you reboot the server? Can you ping the server to check its not a network problem?

Comment: I have rebooted the server, the operating systems loads fine. I can also ssh into the server. All output I have shown is from the server.

Comment: Sadly v14.04 is EOL and so off topic here now. You might get more information about your issue from: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity

Comment: Fair enough, although I doubt this question is in any way related to the version of Ubuntu I am running. I will post the question on serverfault.