# Root filesystem check failed

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, dpkg, fstab

While updating ubuntu my system crashed and after restarting and entering to ubuntu I get the message `Root filesystem check failed.`Very much similar to the post [Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10: Filesystem check or mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361332/ubuntu-13-04-to-13-10-filesystem-check-or-mount-failed). I tried to fix it with the instruction mentioned there as

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot
```

But the problem is after executing `mount -o remount,rw /` I get:

```
mount: cannot remount block device /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk read-write.
is write-protected.
```

After executing `dpkg --configure -a` I get:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system.
```

After executing the remaining commands, nothing happens apart from a reboot at the end.
 Can somebody please suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live CD or USB and supposing that your HDD will be `/dev/sda`, issue this command

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -p -f /dev/sda1
```

assuming that your root partition is the first one, and you have `ext4` on it.

Comment: It gives error `fsck.ext2: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1. You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root`

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: It says: `fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1 /dev/sda1: The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext2/ext4 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the super block is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate super block: e2fsck -b 8193 <device> or e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`

Comment: Ask a professional to help you, or do what the message says. (sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda1) This is a major issue (could be even faulty HDD).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that u forgot to add `sudo` before your commands.You need to be root user if you want to remount( idk if you just ignored the sudos HERE for typing faster)