# Can't boot Ubuntu anymore after attempting upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

I tried to upgrade to the latest Ubuntu version 'Saucy Salamander' and someone in my household logged me out at some point during the process. Now I cant' boot up. The computer goes to a GNU GRUB screen offering a list of verions of Linux. I would be grateful for any help. 
The message I can't get past is :
'Filesystem check of mount failed 
A maintenance check will now start
Control D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re - trying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored
root@matthew ...'

That is it. I can't do anything beyond that point and have to force a shutdown.

My computer is an emachines netbook, small with just USB ports so I was thinking to get a bootable USB as a recovery? Is this a good idea?

Just to update what I am doing. The GNU GRUB gives me 4 options, the first two are to boot with Ubuntu and the 2nd two are memory tests, so now I'm trying those memory tests.

Comment: Memory Test option will not solve your issue, as it is used to check the errors in your Memory(RAM). Do you get the option `Recovery Mode` or something like `Recovery` in the in the `Grub Menu`?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to this well documented question: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/32413) you may find the answer to your problem.

Comment: Managed to boot after configuring dpkg as was suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the GRUB boot menu you can edit the corresponding entry for your Ubuntu installation and add a kernel parameter `fastboot` that makes the boot process skip the file checking and possibly avoiding the early stop you are experiencing. Here are the steps:

1. Select your Ubuntu boot entry and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it
2. Select the `kernel` entry and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit that one too
3. Add the word `fastboot` to end of the line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Hit <kbd>b</kbd> to boot using the new kernel parameter

Now you should probably gain access to your system again and maybe perform a `fsck` on your file system causing the trouble. If this is not the problem, try performing the system upgrade again, this time gracefully.

---

Alternatively, try the solution to this question:

- [Root filesystem check fails after power failure during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation)