# Fixing failed upgrade to 13.10

Tags: installation, upgrade

When I start Ubuntu after it froze during an upgrade to 13.10, it says:

```
Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after retrying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored.
root@Netbook:~#
```

When I use `sudo apt-get update` it eventually says:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to correct the problem

When I run that command, it says:

> dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system

And then gives me the root prompt again. Please help! I'm a VERY basic user of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try remounting your file systems read/write, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write), and then rerunning `dkpg`.  I.e., do

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

See the linked answers for more info if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu usually remounts a file system as read-only if it detects an error with said system (this is done to prevent further file-system errors). To fix this, I would suggest you reboot your system. When the bootloader comes up, select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" option. Select a kernel in Recovery Mode (generally, the newest one on the list should do). Select the option to boot into a root shell. Once in the root shell, run `fsck -f -y /`, and and restart the system using either `reboot`, or `shutdown -r now`. If after this, you still get the same above error, you may have a failing hard drive.