# Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade: Filesystem check or mount failed

Tags: upgrade, mount, filesystem

I had a power failure while upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 and and ended up with a couple of problems. First I ended up the "system is running in low-graphics mode" error described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) and managed to fix it following the described steps. However, currently when I start ubuntu in new version (if I select previous versions on the grub menu I'm fine) I get a filesystem check or mount error

```
Filesystem check or mount failed. A maintenance shell will now be
started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting
after re-trying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored
root@ubuntu-computername:~#
```

similar to the problem described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation).

however I am unable to do

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

as recommended on the second link. I get this error message:

```
cannot remount block device /dev/loop0 read-write, is write-protected
```

any idea how to fix this?

update: Ok, so I ended up giving up and starting fresh but I want to post what little I have learned in case someone else has a similar problem:

there were a few system files and directories that were for some reason empty or damaged, namelly **fstab**, **mstab** and **\tmp**.

and the system was not able to to umount /dev/loop0.

I'm sorry I can't remember much more details of the top of my head, I tried to recover the system with the help of a friend and to be honest, before yesterday I didn't even know **fstab** and **mstab** existed.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to backup and reinstall fresh overwriting everything then restore my personal data from my backup here.

Comment: could you post a copy of your dmesg log? it might show the problem.

Comment: @Warren Hill- yeah, I couldn't resist the temptation

Comment: @Sam- I went over the dmesg log with a friend and it doesn't seem to acuse any problems (saddly I did not save it), nottice that: 1st I started upgrading, then it crashed, the I restarted the upgrade. I am formating the partition and reinstalling fresh but I'll keep the question open with more info in case it happens to someone else