# Issues while installing Ubuntu 14.04 on HP laptop nx 5000

Tags: boot

I need some help. The installation went fine but when restarted I get the following message

```
Serious error were found while checking the disk drive for /.
```

I select option M for manual recovery and it says

```
Root file system check failed.
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Root filesystem check fails after power failure during installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38617/root-filesystem-check-fails-after-power-failure-during-installation)

Comment: @ hi John thanks, so I need to do re-install which should resolve. Is this the solution?

Comment: I think I'd try Scott Wood's answer first since would take a lot less time and it seems that a lot of people have endorsed it.

Comment: Greetings I tried the first command sudo mount -o remount,rw / it says cannot remount block device /host/Ubuntu/disks/root.disk read-write, is write protected.

Comment: Are you doing this from the maintenance shell? (That is, are you taking the option "M" for manual recovery and trying the commands from there?)

Comment: Yes, I am taking option M

Comment: @ John - just to let you know that I am installing by downloading the files in windows XP and it takes around 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same issue. Then I realised that the way I did instllation was wrong. Do it in these steps.

1. Download iso image file (Do not unzip it or run WUBI.exe)
2. Prepare a Bootable USB drive (Need Min 3 GB free space)
3. Download a utility called Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2
4. Run this Utility from your windows environment
5. It will ask for a iso file source, point to that
6. It will also ask for a USB, point to that and it will create the bootable usb for u
7. Now restart ur machine, Go to ROM based set up(F10 or F12)
8. Choose Boot from USB as first priority
9. That will give u option. Ubuntu will load either to be tried or installed. First try and the install..

I am sharing this URL which will guide you. http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/

Comment: Many thanks and I tried above steps with USB and while booting I get the following error message "Error PAE is disabled on this Pentium M" (PAE can be potentially enabled with Kernel Parameter). This installation has become pain for last 1 week now.