# 13.10 to 14.04: Filesystem mount failed: How get to maintenance shell?

Tags: 14.04, mount, filesystem

While upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 we got a power cut: When we restarted the machine we got a system fail; I'm getting the readout below:

'Filesystem check or mount failed. A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored. Enter root password or CONTROL-D to continue maintenance.'

Question: How do I get to maintenance shell stage?

Comment: Enter root password, I guess?

Comment: have a look here.http://askubuntu.com/a/40058/146791

Comment: no idea what root password is. I would like to follow these steps: askubuntu.com/a/40058/146791  but unfortunately cannot get to shell which is the dilemma

Answer (score 1):

Restart the PC and Press and hold the

> SHIFT

Key to get the Advanced options and choose Recovery mode

After reaching this screen choose

[image: drop to shell]

> Drop to root shell prompt

Then Run the command

```
mount -o remount rw /
```

This will make the / as read and write

then do your installation steps

Comment: after selecting 'resume' from the recovery menu I get this: 'you are now going to wait recovery mode and continue the boot sequence. please note that some graphic drivers require a full graphical boot and so will fail when resuming from recovery. if this is the case, simply reboot from the login screen and then perform a standard boot'

Comment: ... then after selecting 'OK' we get: 'FILESYSTEM CHECK OR MOUNT FAILED. A MAINTAINANCE SHELL WILL NOW BE STARTED. CONTROL-D WILL TERMINATE THIS SHELL AND CONT.. BOOT AFTER RETRYING FILESYSTEM. FURTHER ERRORS WILL BE IGNORED. GIVE ROOT PASSWORD FOR MAINTAINANCE OR TYPE CONTROL-D TO CONTINUE'

Comment: pressing SHIFT after restart had no effect so we selected 'UBUNTU, WITH LINUX 3.2.0-67-GENERIC (RECOVERY MODE)' from the menu to get to recovery menu

Comment: give the Root passoword, seems you have already assigned a root password

Comment: no idea what the root password is, I tried various passwords at that stage ...maybe the first password was accepted ... will try that again

Comment: OK  tried first password again and getting:  'root@baboon-H61M-S2OV:(squiggle hashtag)' and a flashing underscore which means I can input

Comment: ok now run the command mount -o remount rw /

Comment: Then try to update restart the network using /etc/init.d/networking restart then upgrade it as before what you done